# Render Partial View in Carousel-Inner Div asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I'm attempting to render a partial view in a Div within the carousel i have created on the home page. The partial view is from a different controller the view code is as seen below. The partial view contains a table which i want to be shown within the carousel div. Currently nothing is being loaded into the div with the code i'm using, i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong. You help would be much appreciated.

**Home Index View**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="margin-top: 30px">

        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="0"></li>
            <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="1" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

        <div class="item active">
            <div id="dvgetpvt">

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <p>
                NuGet is a free Visual Studio extension that makes it easy to add, remove, and update libraries and tools in Visual Studio projects.
            </p>
        </div>              
    </div>

    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>

    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Within the view code i have the following to get the partial view.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
        url: "/crmPVT/GetPVT",
        contentType: "application/html; charset=utf-8",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "html"

    })
    .success(function (result) {
        $('#dvgetpvt').html(result);
    })
    .error(function (xhr, status) {
        alert(status);
    })
</script>
```

The crmPVT controller contains the following code for the partial view

**crmPVT Controller**

```
    public PartialViewResult GetPVT()
    {
        var all = (from e in db.crmPVT
                   where e.Report_ID == 1
                   select e);

        var commnorth = (from e in db.crmPVT
                         where e.Report_ID == 1 &&
                               e.Team.Contains("Commercial North")
                         select e);

        var team = User.Identity.Name == "*****" ? commnorth : all;

        return PartialView(team);
    }
```

Comment: What errors are you getting in the browser console?

Comment: @StephenMuecke No error just nothing showing up

Comment: Have you checked whether your ajax call hits your `GetPVT` action method?